# What is the equivalent of `posix_fallocate()` on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ntfs, sparse-file

NTFS does support [sparse files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-file-operations), but I want to make sure the files I have to write to (which might have been created, set as sparse, and partially filled by another application) are fully allocated, so that I won't get an error due to lack of space when writing to the middle of such file at a later time (i.e. if they are to happen, out of space errors should happen now).

Is there a WinAPI function to ensure a sparse file is fully allocated (preferably atomically), like we have `posix_fallocate()` in POSIX systems? If not, how do I preallocate it?

I don't think these are duplicates:

- [How do you pre-allocate space for a file in C/C++ on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970333/how-do-you-pre-allocate-space-for-a-file-in-c-c-on-windows) - the question is about files in general, which in Windows are non-sparse by default, so the answers don't address how to do it with sparse files.
- [How to create a file of a particular size on windows without io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71636732/how-to-create-a-file-of-a-particular-size-on-windows-without-io) - this question specifically asks about `posix_fallocate()`, but proceeds to ask a question that almost the opposite, i.e. how to create a large file quickly on Windows (for which one commenter suggested NTFS sparse files).

Comment: my be [`SetFileValidData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilevaliddata) (internal this use [`FileValidDataLengthInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/5c9f9d50-f0e0-40b1-9b84-0b78f59158b1) )

Comment: https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/4245

Comment: Hmm, *sparse files* and *fully allocated* are mutually exclusive.  Pick one.

Comment: @RbMm per the link you provided for `FileValidDataLengthInformation`, if the file is sparse I get a `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` error.

Comment: @Eljay They are not. A file can have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE` set, and still happens to be fully allocated.

Comment: Then just make sure that is, indeed, the case.

Comment: @Eljay My question is specifically how. If the file doesn't have the sparse attribute, I'm good. If it does have, what do I do?

Comment: *"If the file is sparse I get a `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` error."* - That is to be [expected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilevaliddata): *"The file cannot be a network file, or be compressed, **sparse**, or transacted."*

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed, so that can't possibly be the answer to my question, as I am asking specifically how to deal with sparse files.

Comment: The answer is: fully allocate the file, don't use sparse files.

Comment: @Eljay I can't, I get the file from the user.

Comment: *sparse file is fully allocated* - this is how ? in this case it already not sparsed file

Comment: @RbMm the full phrase says "I want to make sure the files I have to write to (...) are fully allocated." So sure, in the end, I want a non-sparse file, but I start with a sparse file.

Comment: But in regarding NTFS, the term "sparse file" is overloaded. When Microsoft docs says a file is sparse, it doesn't necessarily mean it has holes in its allocation. Instead, it means the file has a flag set saying that it has the ability of being sparse, so that you may increase its size or poke holes in it to have non-allocated pages. Without this flag, the file is always non-sparse. I don't care if the file has the flag or not, but I do want it to not have any holes.

Comment: `FSCTL_SET_SPARSE` you can use for convert file to not sparse state - based on `SetSparse` true of false

Comment: @RbMm It can't be used to unset the flag. From the docs: "Passing FALSE in the FILE_SET_SPARSE_BUFFER structure will cause this function call to fail. The only way to clear this attribute is to overwrite the file (for example, by calling the CreateFile function with the CREATE_ALWAYS flag)." And as I said, I couldn't care less for the flag, I just want to fill the holes.

Comment: Copying the file would be an option. If you need to allocate disk space, in-place, I wouldn't know of a way other than issuing an `FSCTL_QUERY_ALLOCATED_RANGES` ioctl, followed by a write to every unallocated region.

Comment: more exactly *A value of FALSE for this member is valid only on files that no longer have any sparse regions*, you can qury ranges and fill empty with 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970333/how-do-you-pre-allocate-space-for-a-file-in-c-c-on-windows

Comment: What's the point of this? To get one particular error instead of another? You could encounter an error writing the file even if it isn't sparse. Seems like a lot of hand-wringing for minimal benefit. Just write to the file, and if an error occurs then handle it appropriately.

Comment: @Luke Because the file will be memory mapped, so if I get an error trying to allocate the full file, I can handle it (tell the user the disk is full). But if I try to write to a memory address corresponding to a sparse region of a file, the error will happen inside the page fault that tries to allocate it, killing my process.

Comment: Can you not catch this exception and handle it? Last paragraph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/reading-and-writing-from-a-file-view

Comment: @Luke I am writing a library, but my users can certainly do it. Still, the best place for the application to react to the out of storage errors is where I am trying to do it, so the end user can do something about it.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from catching this in a library. But yes, running out of disk space is awkward to deal with regardless of where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link from [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-file-operations), I could think of 3 ways of pre-allocating the sparse ranges of a file, but none are atomic, like `posix_fallocate()`. I was hoping someone could point to an existing solution in the WinApi.

Here they are:

### Just copy the file

Copy the full file to another, delete the old file, then rename. This approach has the drawback of always being slow, as it has to read and write the whole file, and potentially takes twice the file space on disk.

It could be improved a little by checking the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE`, so you can skip the operation if the file can't be sparse.

### Copy the file inplace

Open the file twice, once for reading and once for writing, and alternate between reading from one side and writing to the other, until the whole file has been rewritten. The performance is as bad as the first solution, but at least doesn't take more space than the full file size.

This (maybe) can be improved by reading and writing only one byte per cluster (if you know the cluster size), because the whole cluster have to be allocated. Allocated clusters will keep the old value, and new clusters will be automatically filled with the default value. I say maybe because writing one byte or one full cluster is the same for the NTFS layer, so maybe it is not worth the extra system calls to `fseek()` the file.

### Write zeros to the sparse region

As suggested in the comments of the question, you can use `FSCTL_QUERY_ALLOCATED_RANGES` to figure out the ranges where the file are allocated, and write zeros to the space between them. Actually, I've read somewhere that the default read value for unallocated ranges is not necessarily zero, so, to be safe, in my implementation I read one byte from one of those regions and use this value to write back to the spaces between allocations.

Again, only one byte per cluster is sufficient.

Depending on how much of the file is allocated, the performance can be much better than the other methods.